# Test difference between totals over periods of different length

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, goodness-of-fit, continuous-data

I have totals for two periods of different lengths (previous month vs month-to-date) and want to test whether they are significantly different.

E.g.

- **1.-30. Nov 2016** = 102.3
- **1.-13. Dec 2016** = 41

If these were count data I'd run a *chi-square for goodness of fit* and adjust the expected values according to the length of the periods.

Is there an equivalent test  for continuous values?

Comment: It will depend on your model of the underlying data-generating process. For example you could model the totals as proportional to counts, and then treat these counts as a "number of events" ([Poisson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) model), or as a "number of successes" ([Binomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) model; in this case "number of trials" would be proportional to time-interval of observation).